How do I find maximum output resolution supported by my buildin graphics output on linux?
How do I find maximum output resolution supported on hdmi by my build-in cpu graphics output on linux? (Fedora, in case that matters).
I know I can just lookup the cpu, but that just gives me the maximum output the cpu support. This might however be limited by driver support and motherboard, so it would be nice to be able to get the maximum supported output, before I buy a new monitor.

Typically it isn't limited either by the driver or the motherboard. It may be limited by the output video connection though.

Try:
$ xrandr --prop, append -d $DISPLAY for the currently used display, if you have more than one.

More insight:
$ echo $DISPLAY
:1

$ xrandr --listmonitors 
Monitors: 1
 0: +*eDP-1 1920/382x1080/215+0+0  eDP-1

$ man xrandr


I thought of that too but it only gives the maximum/native resolution of the connected monitor. That can be and often is less than what the graphics chip can support, which is the question here.

now, I wonder; panels like TFT, LCD, OLED most often have a fixed amount of pixels as far as I know, so cannot adapt (well) to other resolution settings. The gfx-circuitry (GPU or whatever) might be able to generate other resolutions though, but unlikely to be of much use due to the single resolution display hardware. I for one have HW that xrandr reports 49 different settings for, but I find them unlikely to be of much use (not tried though).
